# Geometry Nodes: How to convert instances on points to mesh?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

So I've created a track using this guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTHiRZebl48&list=FL5TUZmEwlbNzpAWDrGCDGmQ&index=5&t=3s&ab_channel=MiroHorvath

[image]

It's a curve with increased resolution, points on it, with instance of mesh on each point. And what is important they are rotated by curve form.

How can I transform them into mesh?

I cannot just apply modifier, it tells me "Cannot apply constructive modifiers on curve. Convert curve to mesh in order to apply."

I cannot use "Object - Apply - Make instances real" - it's just create a ton of new curves with node modifier on it.
[image]

I've tried to transform curve into mesh, than use geometry nodes on it, but seems like it's not working for me too (or I'm just dumb).

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You can't apply geo modifier on the curves, instead of doing node setup on the curve, do it on any mesh object and add your curve using Object Info, also after Instance on Points you need add Realize Instances node to be able to apply geo nodes modifier

Comment: @Higgsas: i cannot really believe the great Higgsas with way more knowledge of geometry nodes as me...didn't know that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can by adding a realize instances node at the end of your node tree and then select your object with the geometry nodes modifier -> object -> convert to mesh

[image]

Comment: It works! Big thanks to you :)